# How to handle a database which is constantly updated from a game

Tags: mysql, database, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game which will store data in a database for multiplayer purposes. A simplified version of the data to be stored is something along the following lines:
Player A goes to a country X on a map and by doing so that country will lose influence over time.

This would be simple enough as the local game could update in the background and then send an update to the database whenever the players stops having an influence there.

The complication comes when:
Player B goes to country X after player A. To check the current influence of country X one of two things need to happen, either A) the influence field in the database updates itself over time, or B) the game constantly updates the database every few seconds when the player A's game updates.

A) sounds like the better option, but I don't actually know if that's possible (is it?) and how much of a strain would that be on the database with a lot of countries?

Sorry if this sounds vague but it seems like a fairly generally applicable scenario for more than just games. If you need any clarification just ask.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, You can do this from database with a [Sql Job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx)

1. Create a SP that calculates influence based on some fields and update it into some column.
2. Call this SP in a job, schedule it to run every 5 mins or whatever time you want.

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it wrong. I'm using mysql while the link you have shared seems to be using mssql.

Comment: @dudledok The essence of the answer may still apply.  It would appear MqSql has an [Event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html) that you could use for the equivalent of _jobs_.  _[Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)_

Comment: Sounds perfect. It seems my web host doesn't support it, which is a shame. I guess I can store the last update time as a column in the table and do it manually.